# (Java) How to fix incompatible types error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have some code that looks like this:

```
public class Name { 
    private char initial1;
    private char initial2;

    public Name(char initial1, char initial2) {
        this(initial1 + initial2);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return initial1 + initial2;
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get 2 errors saying: "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String" with an arrow pointing to the "+ " signs.
How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm calling a superclass by using this(initial1 + initial2) and that I do have another constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You constructor is wrong as well

```
public class Name { 
  private char initial1;
  private char initial2;

  public Name(char initial1, char initial2) {
    this.initial1 = initial1;
    this.initial2 = initial2;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%c%c", initial1 , initial12);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` is treated like a byte, so `initial1 + initial2` returns a byte and not a string. What you want is to convert it to a string first, then concat:

```
public String toString() {
    return Character.toString(initial1) + Character.toString(initial2);
}
```